# Can't call a method from a separate class in Java

Tags: java, methods

making a little mini blog application, just setting up the places to hold the data. I have 3 classes one for the post one for the user and one for the test, which I named Blog. when I try to call the getName(); method in the Blog class it won't run it keeps saying it needs a string, but I made an array of user objects, and input a string for the userName spot, and it still isn't working.

```
    public class Blog
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        User[] userList = new User[3];
        userList[0] = new User("what.com", "TheLegionCrab", "Jake Parham", "jparham@gmail.com");
        userList[1] = new User("huh.com", "RaggleFraggle", "Brett Hawkins", "bhawkins@gmail.com");
        userList[2] = new User("buh.com", "SeanBeast", "Sean Sweeney", "ssweeney@gmail.com");

        for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
        {
            User.getName();
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    private String url; 
    private String userName;
    private String realName;
    private String email;

    public User(String url, String userName, String realName, String email)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.realName = realName;
        this.email = email;
    } 
    public void getName(String userName)
    {
        System.out.println(userName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void getName(String userName)
{
    System.out.println(userName);
}
```

Here your function require a String. That is why it need string to run. If you want to print the userName of the current User object in your loop then use this.

```
public void getName()
{
    System.out.println(this.userName);
}
```

This refer to current User object in your loop.
Now back to your loop.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
    {
        User.getName();
    }
```

You use User class meanwhile you create variable as

```
User[] userList = new User[3];
```

To print from your var, you should use the var.

```
    for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
    {
        userList[counter].getName();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, trying to teach myself, and frustration is running rampant haha

Answer (score 0):

You need to access a `User` instance from your `userList` array (or get an *instance* some other way) to call the method on (and either assign it to a variable and use it *or* just print it). In Java, array access is performed with `[]`. Something like

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < userList.length; counter++)
{
    System.out.println(userList[counter].getName());
}
```

You could also you an enhanced for loop ([for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)) like

```
for (User user : userList) {
    System.out.println(user.getName());
}
```

Also, I don't think `getName` should be [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the class `name` field. You wanted something like,

```
public void getName()
{
    System.out.println(this.userName);
}
```

**or** following the Java practice of returning the value in a getter (and to fix my examples above)

```
public String getName()
{
    return this.userName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you specified that the getName method in the User class takes a String as the argument.  You did that here:

```
public void getName(String userName)
{
    System.out.println(userName);
}
```

So it's working exactly they way you have told it to.

But really, you want "setName()" to take a String arg, and "getName()" to take no arg.  It should look like this:

```
public void setName(String new_userName)
{
    username = new_userName;
}

public void getName()
{
    System.out.println(userName);
}
```

But even then, I'd say that your method names are a bit ambiguous: should I use "getName" to get the username, or to get the realName?
(did you spot the error?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is to print the name of the user instance instead of the parameter to the getName method. Try this defining the method like this:

```
    public void getName()
    {
        System.out.println(this.userName);
    }
```

and in the main method:

```
User[] userList = new User[3];
userList[0] = new User("what.com", "TheLegionCrab", "Jake Parham", "jparham@gmail.com");
userList[1] = new User("huh.com", "RaggleFraggle", "Brett Hawkins", "bhawkins@gmail.com");
userList[2] = new User("buh.com", "SeanBeast", "Sean Sweeney", "ssweeney@gmail.com");

for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
{
     userList[counter].getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

a) Calling getName() without any object i.e as a static function. Instead use the objects created and call it as:

```
userList[counter].getName();
```

b)Creating User objects with the name (in constructor) and also calling getName with argument i.e userName. This is wrong/not needed. When you created the object, you have already informed the object about the userName. So have a clean getter without any argument.

```
getName()
```

The code:

```
public class Blog
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        User[] userList = new User[3];
        userList[0] = new User("what.com", "TheLegionCrab", "Jake Parham", "jparham@gmail.com");
        userList[1] = new User("huh.com", "RaggleFraggle", "Brett Hawkins", "bhawkins@gmail.com");
        userList[2] = new User("buh.com", "SeanBeast", "Sean Sweeney", "ssweeney@gmail.com");


        for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
        {
            userList[counter].getName(); # Correct this to use the created objects.
        }
    }
}

public class User
{
    private String url; 
    private String userName;
    private String realName;
    private String email;

    public User(String url, String userName, String realName, String email)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.realName = realName;
        this.email = email;
    } 
    public void getName() #Remove the argument.
    {
        System.out.println(this.userName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the object of the User class before calling else your User class should be static to call it direct.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter<userList.length; counter++)
    {   User obj = new User();
        obj.getName();
    }
```

else

```
public static User
```

{

```
public User(String url, String userName, String realName, String email)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.realName = realName;
    this.email = email;
} 
public void getName(String userName)
{
    System.out.println(userName);
}
```

}